# Error loading CSV with MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/home/rep/saloncodeforde.csv' INTO TABLE account_code
```

My table has 3 columns, as does my CSV (`id int`, `zipc varchar` and `ph varchar`).

The result is ok for ID column but for `zipc` and `ph`, I get `NULL`.

Comment: I'm getting `NULL` reading your question. Do you get `NULL` when you insert your file into the table, or when `SELECT`ing out of it? You need to give us an example of your CSV. Please put some effort into your questions.

Comment: A line in csv loks like this : 100022 34500 467493279.
the table columns Id int, zipc varchar(30), phone varchar(30).

Comment: sorry, but editor in this site make impossible to present well some questions

Answer (score 0):

Try using more complete syntax. Reference link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

For instance:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/home/rep/saloncodeforde.csv'
       INTO TABLE account_code
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';

There are also parameters for end-of-line terminators, escape characters, and optional field enclosures (such as quotes around strings with spaces, though I doubt you have those in your data as described).